# Python OpenCV: ImportError Module Not Found

Tags: python, opencv

I had installed OpenCV, and it was working just fine. But I noticed that a few libraries were missing.

So I decided to install another copy. I moved the working copy to another directory, and started the install of the new one. I was having trouble with this new install, so I cancelled it and moved my old OpenCV install back to its original directory.

But now, my old install doesn't work anymore. Each time I try to run something, it says "ImportError: No module named cv2" or "ImportError: No module named cv" (depending on what was being imported in the file).

What do I do to fix this? I remember encountering a similar issue the first time I installed and ran this copy of OpenCV, and something had to be changed with the Python Path to work correctly. I can't quite remember, and I'm kind of confused about why those settings would change, if they indeed have.

Please let me know what I can do to rectify this. I am using OS X 10.9. Thank you.

UPDATE: I added this to my .bash_profile: export PYTHONPATH=/Users/santosh/opencv-2.4.7/build/lib:$PYTHONPATH. But now when I run opencv samples, I get "Segmentation fault: 11". Any thoughts?

Comment: How many versions of Python do you have?

Comment: I'm unsure about that, though the version that is active right now is 2.6.9. I just installed the newest opencv from sourceforge and I tried to run some of the demo files, and I'm getting the same message.